# Frida is it possible to change enum values

Tags: android, enums, frida

I am playing with [Frida](https://frida.re/) and exploring its functionality using an APP where I place hooks on.
The app has an enum somewhere:

`enum AppMode{ debug, release }`

In the app a lot of functions use the following comparison:

`public void ExampleFunction(){ AppMode appmode = AppMode.release; if(appmode == AppMode.debug){ ... } }`

I am wondering if it is possible with Frida to change the value of 'AppMode.release' in a way so it would be the same value as 'AppMode.debug'.
This would be an efficient method into having the whole app act like it is in debug mode.

I searched online for solutions. I am aware that frida can only hook FUNCTIONS but I am wondering, maybe there is a core enum-function that fetches the ordinal of a enumvalue when assigning a variable with an enum value.

Comment: Enums are converted to a class and each enum value becomes a `.field public static final enum`. If you compare a value to an enum in an if clause the value of this field is loaded (`sget-object`). Not sure if frida is capable of changing a final field value, but if it is possible it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are converted to a class and each enum value becomes a `.field public static final enum`. If you compare a value to an enum in an if clause the value of this field is loaded (`sget-object`).

To get an understanding let's look at an example:

Java code:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C, D, E
}
```

Relevant Smali code of `MyEnum`:

```
.class final enum Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;
.super Ljava/lang/Enum;

.field public static final enum A:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;

.field public static final enum B:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;

.field public static final enum C:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;

.field public static final enum D:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;

.field public static final enum E:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;
```

And this way it is used:

```
    private static void test(MyEnum me) {
        if (me == MyEnum.C) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "C");
        } 
    }
```

```
.method private static test(Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;)V
    .registers 3
    .param p0, "me"    # Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;

    // in next line the enum value for comparison is loaded
    sget-object v0, Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum;->C:Lcom/example/myapplication/MyEnum; 

    const-string v1, "MainActivity"

    // the actual comparison is in the next line
    if-ne p0, v0, :cond_c

    const-string v0, "C"

    invoke-static {v1, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    cond_c:
...
```

You can see the `sget-object` call that loads the enum value for comparison in `if-ne`. So changing the value of the field `C` will change the value that is loaded for comparison.

Frida code:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    
    let enumClass = Java.use("com.example.myapplication.MyEnum");
    enumClass.C.value = enumClass.A.value;

});
```

So you just have to replace `C` from the example with `debug` and `A` with `release`.

Comment: this is exactally what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: @tineproens Feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer. This is the way to say thank you in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would but I need 15 reputation in order to be allowed to vote unfortunately...